# Delayed expansion of command line variables

Tags: command-line, terminal, command-prompt

i want to do this in one command:

```
set myvar="hello" && echo %myvar%
```

and get "hello" on the screen.
but i get %myvar% instead. How can this expansion be done immediately so i get "hello"?

**Edit:**
how does it look like when using angle brackets:

```
set "var=<hello>"& echo %^var%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 - use CALL to get an extra round of expansion**

The CALL command introduces an extra round of expansion. But you don't want the variable to be expanded before the CALL is executed, otherwise you will get the value that existed before the line was executed (assuming it already existed). So you need a way to delay the expansion.

Within a batch script, you would use `call echo %%myvar%%`, but doubling percents does not work on the command line.

The trick to get it to work on the command line is to introduce a dissappearing caret into the name. The normal expansion interprets the caret as part of the name, so the variable is not found, and nothing is expanded. The caret is consumed before the CALL expansion, so the correct result is then obtained.

```
set "myvar=hello"&call echo %^myvar%
```

*Note that this will not work in the unlikely event that variable named `^myvar` actually exists.*

**Option 2 - persistently enable delayed expansion**

```
cmd /v:on
set "myvar=hello"&echo !myvar!
```

**Option 3 - temporarily enable delayed expansion**

```
set "myvar=hello"&cmd /v:on /c echo !myvar!
```

---

***Update for edited question***

If your variable contains poison characters like `<` or `>`, then your best choice is to use Option 2 or 3 because delayed expansion is immune to poison characters.

The obvious way you could use option 1 is if you escape the poison characters during the definition.

```
set "myvar=^<hello^>"&call echo %^myvar%
```

Not a very practical solution.

I suppose you could do the following to avoid delayed expansion and avoid modifying the content:

```
set "myvar=<hello>"&for /f "delims=" %A in ('echo ^"%^myvar%^"') do @echo %~A
```

But this can have problems if your variable content might have embedded quotes.

Comment: does this work for every possible situation, e.g. also for echo %myvar:~1,-1%, where i want to exclude the first and last symbol

Comment: @Sandra - Sure does. The caret can be anywhere between the opening percent and the colon. Give it a try.

Comment: your last comment with avoiding the delayed expansion , isnt that supposed to be set myvar=<hello> without the escaping?. And what exactly does it do?

Comment: @Sandra - yes, thanks. I edited the answer. It is convoluted syntax needed to successfully echo the value of a variable containing poison characters, without quotes in the output, without escaping the value, and without using delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this at the command line as opposed to in a batch:

```
set myvar="hello" && call echo %myvar%
```

Comment: This only works if myvar is undefined at the start. If it is already defined then the original value is echoed.